# Java drawImage interpolation

Tags: java, interpolation, bufferedimage, graphics2d, drawimage

My question involves the **drawImage** method in **Java Graphics2D** (this is for a desktop app, not Android).

My **BufferedImage** that I'd like to draw contains high resolution binary data, most pixels are black but I have some sparse green pixels (the green pixels represent data points from an incoming raw data stream). The bitmap is quite large, larger than my typical panel size. I made it large so I could zoom in and out. The problem is when I zoom out I lose some of my green pixels .. as an example if my image is 1000 pixels and by panel is 250 pixels, I'd lose 1 out of 4 pixels in each direction (X and Y). If I use nearest neighbor interpolation when I scale the pixels can just disappear to black. If I use something like bilinear interpolation my green pixel will get recolored to somewhere between black and green.

I understand all this behavior, but my question is that is there any way to get the behavior I want, which is to make sure if any pixels is non-black I want it to be drawn at it's full intensity. Perhaps something like a "max-hold" interpolation.

I realize I could probably do what I want by drawing shape primitive over a black background, and maybe this is what I'll have to do. But there is a reason I'm using bitmaps (has to do with the fact that I'm showing the data in a falling spectrogram-type display - and it does have a mode where all the pixels could be colored and not just black and green).

Thanks,

Comment: You could scan the image and paint pixel-per-pixel using your own interpolation algorithm, but that would be probably slow. You can try finding something at [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) or [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) as well. But I really think you should render the scene using drawing primitives, for performance reasons.

Comment: *"lose 1 out of 4 pixels in each direction"*  No, 3 out of 4.

Comment: @oldrinb `RescaleOp` is not used to change the size of an image, but to apply a linear function on the color values of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the implementation of drawImage and override it to get your desired behaviour, however probably the core of the scaling uses hardware acceleration, so re implementing it in Java would be really slow.

You could look into JOGL,  but my impression is that, if your pixels are really sparse,  just drawing the green pixels on a black background (or over an image) would be both easy to code and very fast. 
You could even have an heuristic switching between painting the dots to scaling the image if the number of dots starts being too high.